# Why do I get indexerror list index out of range (python sys.argv)?

Tags: python-3.x

```
from sys import argv
action = argv[1]
```

Python 3.5

From command line I enter: file.name argument

Comment: shouldn't it be `action = argv[0]`? Python uses zero-based arrays so your first parameter would be with index 0.

Comment: Its running perfectly on my system. Can you upload a small video/screenshots of your problem?

Comment: action = argv[0] returns the actual file. It's a string of it's location.

Comment: Screenshots: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8oncbyt72063xzm/1.jpg?dl=0 https://www.dropbox.com/s/fvbsd2698xbx9w6/2.jpg?dl=0 it's running on my working laptop but at home I have this problem. Both windows. 7 at work, 8.1 at home.

Comment: could you add your complete error log? on win 10 python 3.5 I get no such problem